# Are these subsets open, closed, both or neither?

Tags: general-topology

I'm teaching myself topology using a text I found online. Right now I'm reviewing "Metrics." Please let me know if my answers are correct, and If my reasoning is accurate and complete.

I think (c)and (d) are correct, but my reason could be better stated. (not sure how)

.............................................
In each part below, a subset $S$ of a metric space $M$ is given. In each case decide whether $S$ is open, closed, both or neither.

(a)$M = \mathbb{R},$ and $S = [0,1)$

**Neither.** S is not open because the point {0} cannot have an open ball around it contained in $S$. S is not closed because $M-S$ has the point {1}, and it cannot have an open ball around it contained in $M-S$.

(b)$M = \mathbb{R},$ and $S =  \mathbb{N}$

**Closed.** $M-S = ...(0,1) \cup (1,2) \cup (2,3)...$ So $M-S$ is a union of arbitrarily many open subsets of M, and thus an open subset of M. And since the complement of S is open, S is closed. *Not open* because the point {1}, for example, can not have a ball around it contained in $S$

(c)$M = \mathbb{Z},$ and $S =  \mathbb{N}$

**Both.** $B_{0.5}(3)=\{3\}$ is open, and $\overline B_{0.5}(3)=\{3\}$ is closed. Thus S is both, since every subset is a finite union of singletons, and finite unions preserve both openness and closedness.

(d)$M = \mathbb{R}^2,$ and $S$ is the set of point with rational coordinates

**Both.** Rational numbers are countably infinite, and thus a infinite union of singletons. Ergo, the argument for (c) applies.

(e)$M = \mathbb{R}^2,$ and $S$ is the unit disk $\{ (x,y) \in  \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2<1  \}$.

**Open.** This is a 2 dimensional open ball, and an open ball is an open set. *Not Closed* because $(1,0) \in M-S$, and $(1,0)$ cannot have a ball around it contained in $M-S$.

(f)$M = \mathbb{R}^3,$ and $S$ is the unit disk $\{ (x,y,z) \in  \mathbb{R}^3: z=0 $ and $ x^2+y^2<1  \}$.

**Neither.** *Not open*, because if a ball is formed at any point on the unit disk, it will contain points in M that are not on the disk, thus it does not contain a open ball around each of its points.  *Not closed*, because the compliment of S is  \mathbb{R}^3 with the disk removed, thus it contains the unit circle ($ z=0 $ and $ x^2+y^2=1$); The points on the unit circle are boundary points, and don't have open balls.

(g)$M =\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 :x>0 $ and $y>0 \},$ and $S = \{ (x,y) \in M:x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$.

**Closed.** $M-S$ does not contain any boundary points (they are all in S), and is therefor open, which implies that S is closed. *Not open*, because the points on $x^2+y^2=1 are boundary points and thus don't have open balls.

Comment: (d) is wrong: infinite unions do not preserve closedness. Also singletons are not open and thus infinite unions of singletons are not necessarily open.

Comment: Thank you. I'll rethink my argument and revise it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jooi is correct about (d) being wrong.  Your flaw when applying (c)'s logic to (d) is that in (d), $B_{0.5}(3,3) \neq \left\{(3,3)\right\}$, so points of $S$ are not open in $M$.  As for closed, what are the boundary points of $S$?

Looking back at (c) I see another issue.  You say every subset of $S$ is a *finite* union of singletons.  This isn't true.   But in the discrete topology (where points are open sets), every set is open, therefore every set is closed.

Comment: Is the set of rational numbers considered discrete?

Comment: @MichaelMaliszesky: In the subspace topology from the real numbers, no.

Comment: I put my corrections here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403218/are-these-subsets-open-closed-both-or-neither-revised