# Are these subsets open, closed, both or neither (revised)?

Tags: general-topology

This is a follow up to [Are these subsets open, closed, both or neither?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401711/are-these-subsets-open-closed-both-or-neither)

Please let me know if my answers are correct, and If my reasoning is accurate and complete.
Below are my corrections: 

.......................................

(c)$M = \mathbb{Z},$ and $S =  \mathbb{N}$

**Both.** For any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $B_{0.5}(x)=  \overline B_{0.5}(x)=\{x\}$, therefor M is a discrete metric space, and every subset is both open and closed.

(d)$M = \mathbb{R}^2,$ and $S$ is the set of points with rational coordinates

**Neither.** The set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q} ⊂ \mathbb{R}$ is neither open nor closed. It isn't open because every neighborhood of a rational number contains irrational numbers, and its complement isn't open because every neighborhood of an irrational number contains rational numbers.Thus points with rational coordinates are also neither open or closed.

Comment: Reasoning in $(d)$ is fine assuming the topology is the standard one. In $(c)$ you forgot to mention what topology you are using.

Comment: Your answers and reasoning are correct. However, for (d), the set $S$ is $\mathbb{Q}^2$, not $\mathbb{Q}$. So each reference to "rational number" should really be "point with rational coordinates". And be careful: the complement of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is the set of points where at least one coordinate is irrational, not the set of points with both coordinates irrational.